# Sinatra route returning enumerator instead of json object

Tags: json, sinatra, ruby-datamapper

I am trying to do the following in a sinatra route:

```
get '/posts/:id' do
  Post.find(params[:id]).to_json
end
```

But this is returning an enumerator.

How do I access a single object in json format?

PS I'm using datamapper

***EDIT***

I managed to return the json value by using *get* instead of *find*:

```
get '/posts/:id' do
  Post.get(params[:id]).to_json
end
```

If someone can explain why I will accept answer so not to waste the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find` doesn't exist in DataMapper. It's a method of Ruby's Enumerable, that returns an enumerator object ; which you're trying to convert to JSON.

DataMapper objects apparently implement Enumerable, that's why you don't get an *undefined method* exception.

Enumerable#find: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find

Comment: I'm used to using .find with activerecord so thanks for clearing it up

Answer (score 0):

Find method  return an enumerator  not the entry. 
If you expect only ONE entry : try this

```
Post.first(params[:id]).to_json
```